# regex js - how I can get hashtags with åäö from text

Tags: javascript, regex, hashtag

I need parse hashtags from text with special characters such as åäö

For now, I use

```
var regexp = /\B\#\w\w+\b/g; // todo åäö
var result = "some text #hashtagäöå  other text ".match(regexp);
```

If I have text like "some text #hashtagäöå  other text " this regexp return only "#hashtag".

How I can get "#hashtagäöå"?

Thanks!

```
var regexp = /\B\#[a-zA-Z\x7f-\xff]+/g; --- this works
```

Comment: `var regexp = /\B\#\w\w+\bäöå/g;`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Actually this isn't a duplicate. If you look at the other question, you'll see that the results that the OP expected isn't just words that start with hashtags, and the same goes for the answers given. This post only wants to extract words starting with a hashtag, including words with unicode characters.

Comment: Yes, does adding `#` make a huge difference? See https://jsfiddle.net/xjw5j23o/. 10 second work.